# How to get a value based on a key from KeyValuePair data stored in one cell in oracle database

Tags: sql, json, oracle, key-value

lets say i have a table like that

```
id name             address                     Doc
1  {1:mark,2:john}  {1:Home,2:Work,3:Club}      {NI:299,Pass:A159}
2  {1:Max,2:Mo}     {1:Home}                    {NI:300011}
```

what i want is to write a qurey to select a value from cell based on the key
for example

```
i want the value which has key = 2 in column named(Name) where id=1
```

so it should return

```
john
```

and so on.
so how can i do something like that without using substring?

Comment: Why can't we use substring?

Comment: because this table is gonna be dynamic, by dynamic i mean that address can include new keys say 4 or 5 not always gonna be 3 or 1,2,3 
so i want to make a generic sql script that only gives me values based on a key i enter

Comment: Those json values are not valid !

Comment: @SelVazi let's say its a key value pair not particularly a jason

Comment: @Mark - why does varying the key you're looking for mean you can't use substr? You need to find the offsets anyway, even if you were always looking for key 2?

Answer (score 2):

Your `name` column is not valid JSON so you cannot use JSON functions.

You could use regular expressions but they are slower than simple string functions. So, even though you said you do not want to use `SUBSTR`, you should use `SUBSTR`:

```sql
SELECT id,
       CASE
       WHEN spos > 0 AND epos > 0
       THEN SUBSTR(name, spos + 3, epos - spos - 3)
       END AS name2
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         name,
         INSTR(TRANSLATE(name, '{}', ',,'), ',2:', 1) AS spos,
         INSTR(
           TRANSLATE(name, '{}', ',,'),
           ',',
           INSTR(TRANSLATE(name, '{}', ',,'), ',2:', 1, 1) + 3
         ) AS epos
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, name) AS
SELECT 1, '{1:mark,2:john}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '{1:Max,2:Mo}'    FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | NAME2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | john |
| 2 | Mo |

If you only want when `id = 1` then add that filter and if you want to make the index you are matching a more dynamic parameter then:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN spos > 0 AND epos > 0
       THEN SUBSTR(name, spos + 3, epos - spos - 3)
       END AS name
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         name,
         INSTR(TRANSLATE(name, '{}', ',,'), ','||index_to_match||':', 1) AS spos,
         INSTR(
           TRANSLATE(name, '{}', ',,'),
           ',',
           INSTR(TRANSLATE(name, '{}', ',,'), ','||index_to_match||':', 1, 1) + 3
         ) AS epos
  FROM   table_name
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT 2 AS index_to_match FROM DUAL)
  WHERE  id = 1
)
```

Or use a parameterised query and a bind parameter (instead of a sub-query).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wtsH-nr8)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a valid json values :

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id int,
  name  VARCHAR2 (200) ,          
  address VARCHAR2 (200),                    
  Doc VARCHAR2 (200),
  CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (name IS JSON)
);

insert into mytable 
select 1,  '{"1":"mark","2":"john"}', '{"1":"Home","2":"Work","3":"Club"}', '{"NI":299,"Pass":"A159"}' from dual union all
select 2,  '{"1":"Max","2":"Mo"}', '{"1":"Home"}', '{"NI":300011}' from dual
```

The query can be :

```
select t.name."2"
from mytable t
where id = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/dC35ppRa)

---

If there are only key-value values in a non-valid JSON, then:

```
with cte as (
  select REGEXP_REPLACE(name,
                 '([a-zA-Z0-9-]+):([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)',
                 '"\1":"\2"') as name
  from mytable t
  where id = 1
)
select json_value(name, '$."2"')
from cte
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/gWSVGWSi)

Answer (score 1):

If your data is as shown and isn't JSON (or quoted) and performance isn't a primary concern (if it is then go back to `substr()`, as @MT0 showed) then you could use [`regexp_substr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099) to find the match, with a pattern that embeds the key value you want:

```
select regexp_substr(name, '({|,)' || 2 || ':(.*?)(,|})', 1, 1, null, 2) as result
from your_table
where id = 1
```

| RESULT |
| --- |
| john |

Your script will need to supply the first `2` in the first line, and the `1` in the third line; so more generically with bind variables:

```
select regexp_substr(name, '({|,)' || :p_key || ':(.*?)(,|})', 1, 1, null, 2) as result
from your_table
where id = :p_id
```

The pattern is looking for `{` or `,`, followed by your key value, followed by a colon `:`; and capturing everything up to another `,` or `}`. The other arguments are there to tell it to return the second capture group (the second `2` in that line). The first group is the 'or' of `({|,)`, and you want the second group `(.*?)` which is the value for that pair.

By varying the key value you get different results; with the same column and `1`:

```
select regexp_substr(name, '({|,)' || 1 || ':(.*?)(,|})', 1, 1, null, 2) as result
from your_table
where id = 1
```

| RESULT |
| --- |
| mark |

And you can use the same approach with the other key/value columns.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/L7NIKu1q)

Of course, it would be better to store the data relationally, not as key/value pairs within a string column.